# Multiple Javascript conflict

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get 2 scripts to run on the same page but they won't play nice with each other.  One is called TabTop http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/tabtop.htm and the other is Clic*Pic http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/gallery.htm, both by isdntek.  I can get either one of them to run fine all by themselves, but not both together.  I looked around and tried to find the answer to this problem by myself, but to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate any help that can be provided.

Thanks!

Comment: We'll need to see your test page...

Comment: Define "won't play nice with each other."  Is there a specific problem?  Do you have some specific code to reproduce this problem?  Or should we just guess?

Comment: You're probably better off asking the author of those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each script in a self calling function:

```
(function(){
  //As long as you don't use global variables
  //the content here is protected from any interaction with the outside
})();
```

Now, if both codes use global variables, the task will be unfortunately harder.

Answer (score 0):

The RainbowCodeModule6.js file is used by both pages, it sets a very large number of global variables (quite a few because it doesn't declare local variables within functions), so it is quite possible that with two scripts trying to use the same set of globals, they are getting conflicts. e.g. (my wrapping for posting here)

```
function changeShades(color){ //--update the vertical column of light/dark shades
    var ymax=paletteymax
    if (!color){return}
    for (i=0; i<ymax; i++){
    document.getElementById('colorShades'+i).
           style.backgroundColor=colorBrightness(color,(ymax-1-i)/(ymax-1))
    }
}
```

The above doesn't keep it's counter `i` local and depends on the global `paletteymax`. I can't say if that's your problem, but it is indicative of poor programming and application architecture. Another example:

```
function dec2hex(R,G,B) { //--Converts three R-G-B components to
                          //  a single internet hex color
    var hexTest="0123456789ABCDEF";
    Rd_hi=R/16; Rd_lo=R%16;
    Rd=hexTest.substr(Rd_hi,1)+hexTest.substr(Rd_lo,1)
    Gn_hi=G/16; Gn_lo=G%16;
    Gn=hexTest.substr(Gn_hi,1)+hexTest.substr(Gn_lo,1)
    Bu_hi=B/16; Bu_lo=B%16;
    Bu=hexTest.substr(Bu_hi,1)+hexTest.substr(Bu_lo,1)
    hexval='#'+Rd+Gn+Bu
    return hexval;
  }
```

Why they decided to keep `hexTest` local but let all the other variables go global is beyond me. Variables `R`, `G` and `B` are also global, but here they are kept local because they are formal parameters in the function declaration.

It also uses document.write to write a table in parts, which is never a good idea. I think it's just a poorly written script, find something else.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, I can't locate anything else that will produce the results I need and I'm unable to write it myself.